LaTeX Minted Package with Pygments in Texifier on MacOS
I have already installed the MacTeX distribution on Mac, but when I used minted package, it throws out the following error:
Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package

I have also installed the pygments package on conda, but it seems LaTeX cannot find it.
Tried to reinstall MacTeX and anaconda, but it didn't work.

Conda usually installs stuff inside an isolated environment whereas LaTeX expects to find it  globally. You can change your PATH environment variable accordingly but it would be easier to install pygments globally (e.g. via MacPorts or Homebrew) rather than via Conda (or create a suitable Conda default environment).

Can you show your .log file? Do you have shell-escape enabled?

Do you compile your document from the command lind or some editor?

Make sure you added the pygmentize to the PATH.
You can do it by first finding the PATH of pygmentize by typing the following into your Mac's terminal:
which pygmentize

After you get the PATH, go to Finder on your Mac and press command + shift + G. Then, paste the PATH. This will take you to the folder where pygementize executable file is stored.
Cope the executable to the following PATH:
/usr/local/bin

Finally, re-open your Texifier and make sure you import your minted package with the following code:
\usepackage[outputdir=.texpadtmp]{minted}

Note: Since you asked for the solution for MacOS, this only works on MacOS.

You cannot just copy executables from one path to another. This might work but it’s not reliable; and at any rate the regular user has no permission to write to /usr/local/bin, for good reason. Using a proper package manager will take care of installing tools in their proper location.

Hi, just tried to copy the executable, it works perfectly! Thank you @future-liang

@Julia Please, for the sake of your future self, don’t use this “solution”, it’s bad; see my comment above. You are messing with your computer’s configuration. This will create frustrating problems in the future.

@KonradRudolph Thank you for your suggestion! I have also just find this very same solution on other forum, which I think it's quite reliable for this specific problem. Other package manager like homebrew just don't work as I've tried.

@KonradRudolph I totally agree with you, but for the specific case with pygments package installed with conda, copying it is a fast solution, and won't mess with other system executables. Using other global package manager would be a better solution though :)

@Julia you will end up with an outdated binary, which won't get updated by conda etc. Better make latex find pygments at its actual location.
